# How to use multiple conditioned responses outside Watson assistant?

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-watson

How to enable Multiple conditioned responses in Watson assistant for using external web page. I have tried but when I ask Multiple conditioned responses but the reply was "I didn't understand. You can try rephrasing.".Why its happening is there any way to solve it?

I have tried many ways ...tried for weeks but nothing solves the issue.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b2BwY.jpg)

Comment: I don't understand your question. Could you share an example of inputs and expected outputs and how you configured the dialog node(s) in Watson Assistant?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Multiple conditioned responses are shown in the response only when both `If assistant recognizes` condition and the condition under `Assistant responds` evaluates to TRUE.

Based on the image(screenshot) you have uploaded, I don't see any condition evaluating to TRUE in the `IF assistant recognizes` section.

Here's an example where both the conditions evaluate to TRUE. If you see in the query there is a percentage (recognized by  @sys-percentage entity) and `YES` recognized by the intent `#yes`

[image]

Example conditions

- $unanswered_counter > 2 *context variable example*
- #where-is and @location:restaurant - *Evaluates to TRUE when the query is **Where is the restaurant?***

To better understand multiple conditioned responses, refer to this [post](https://medium.com/ibm-watson/bot-deconstructed-995c18fe1262) and also the `Anything else` node in this [post](https://tutorials.botsfloor.com/differentiating-the-same-with-watson-conversation-795c0660f072)

The response won’t be any different if you are querying the Assistant from an external webpage